# Internal List containing Dictionary Keys does not deallocating memory even after removing keys from the dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management, dictionary, python-internals

I am using dictionaries in my python script written in python 2.7.

when i ran my script using **pympler** to find memory leakage,I found that the size of list object is increasing incredibly.

**And these list contains the keys of these dictionary.Is these list in build implementation of python dictionary?**

Output of  pympler is as following:

```
                         types |   # objects |   total size
  ============================ | =========== | ============
                    list |       99221 |    106.53 MB
                     str |      105530 |      6.06 MB
                    dict |         602 |    940.48 KB
                    code |        1918 |    239.75 KB
                     int |       10043 |    235.38 KB
      wrapper_descriptor |        1120 |     87.50 KB
                    type |          87 |     76.80 KB
 builtin_function_or_method |         719 |     50.55 KB
       method_descriptor |         601 |     42.26 KB
                     set |         132 |     33.41 KB
                 weakref |         372 |     31.97 KB
                   tuple |         364 |     26.24 KB
     <class 'abc.ABCMeta |          20 |     17.66 KB
       member_descriptor |         233 |     16.38 KB
     function (__init__) |         114 |     13.36 KB
```

The size of list is increasing and the RES memory for the scipt is also incresing?
The list contains keys of the dictionary used which which i think is the internal implementation of dictionary.
**Is the keys stored as list in memory?How could i manage this memory leakage?**

Here is the code for the above output:

```
         from pympler import tracker
         from pympler import summary
         from pympler import muppy
         import types
         while(1):
          d={}
          for i in range(1000,1100):
             d[i]=1
          for i in range(1000,1050):
            del d[i]
          all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
          sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
          summary.print_(sum1) 
          type = muppy.filter(all_objects, Type=types.ListType)
          print 'length :%s'%(len(type))
```

Comment: Your title contains an assertion that your question reveals as an assumption. Have you tested this? Could you provide a minimal example that others could use to recreate this behaviour?

Comment: "The list contains keys of the dictionary used which which i think is the internal implementation of dictionary." Nope; the internal implementation of a dictionary does not have any lists. See [`dictobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4e81b20e7a57/Objects/dictobject.c) for how they actually work.

Comment: I have edited my question with the sample code.I have tested the code the code and the pympler output is also showed

Comment: Meanwhile: Removing items from a dict is not guaranteed to shrink the dict's hash table, and in most implementations will either never or very rarely do so. If you have a dict that's become much smaller than its transient maximum size and really need to compact it, the simplest way is to just make a copy.

Comment: Then why the size of type 'list' is increasing ,when i use no list in the script?The list contains keys of the dictionary.

Comment: @titto.sebastian: The list the keys of the dictionary because it contains every single thing that exists, which includes the keys of the dictionary, and a list of, among other things, the previous keys of the dictionary, and a list of, among other things, the previous list (which contains the doubly-previous keys) and the previous keys, and so on ad infinitum. See my answer. And be more careful with your assumptions, or provide enough information for people to check them instead of just expecting us to trust them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is an artifact of testing things poorly.

In your loop, you do this:

```
all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
```

You never delete `all_objects`, so the previous list of all objects is still a live object at the time you call `get_objects`. Of course you drop that reference when you assign the new list to `all_objects`, but that's too late; the new list of all objects now has a reference to the old list of all objects.

This is actually a common problem with people using all kinds of in-process memory debugging tools—it's easy to end up keeping around artifacts of the tool and end up debugging those artifacts.

One nice way to make sure you don't accidentally do this kind of thing is to factor out your muppy code into a function:

```
def summarize():
    all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
    sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
    summary.print_(sum1) 
    type = muppy.filter(all_objects, Type=types.ListType)
    print 'length :%s'%(len(type))
```

Now, in the loop, you can just call `summarize()`, and be sure that you can't have any local variables lying around that you didn't want.